# Twisted HTTP server authentication

Tags: curl, twisted.web, twisted.client

I am following following tutorial for http server authentication
http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=502&cpage=1#comment-1959
I can run the server on my localhost but how can I login to server.
The user name password of the server are temporarily save in dict in this file.
I used curl -d -F and --user method to login to user but no success.
Please tell me what is protocol for http authenticaion for this server.
Thanks

Comment: I found out that it is using head method for authentication. So how we send username password in head method?

Comment: here is solution
curl -u admin:aaa http://localhost:8801/example/

Answer (score 0):

yeah I found the solution.
curl -u username:pass http://host.com/example